# how to find that how many times a while loop has get executed?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Sample program in which `while` loop is illustrated:

```
answer="0"
while answer!="4":
    answer=input("What is 2 + 2?")
    if answer!="4":
        print("Wrong...Try again.")
    else:
        print("Yes! 2 + 2 = 4")
```

Here the loop will execute till the user gives the correct answer, i.e. 4.

I want to add another feature in the above code which prints how many attempts the user took to give the correct answer.

```
print("You gave correct answer in attempt",answer)
```

But I am not getting any idea how to do it.

Comment: Remove the "s from around your numbers; answer=0 while answer != 4..

Comment: Just add an integer that you increment everytime the user fails. Then when it succeeds you can display the integer value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently working through some tutorials on Python, so if it doesn't work, do excuse my n00b level...

```
answer=0
attempts = 0
while answer!=4:
    answer=input("What is 2 + 2?")
    if answer!=4:
        print("Wrong...Try again.")
        attempts = attempts + 1
    else:
        print("Yes! 2 + 2 = 4")

print("You gave correct answer in %d attempts" % attempts)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable which stores the amount of attempts the user has taken:

```
attempts = 0 

while True:
    answer = int(raw_input("What is 2 + 2?"))
    attempts += 1
    if answer == 4: 
        print("Yes! 2 + 2 = 4")
        break
    print "Wrong.. try again"

print "It took {0} amount of attempts".format(attempts)
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `while`-loop into a `for`-loop:

```
from itertools import count

for attempts in count(1):
    answer = input("What is 2 + 2?")
    if answer == "4":
        break
    print("Wrong...Try again.")
print("Correct in {} attempts!".format(attempts))
```